# How to load class files into a project to create an object

Tags: java, class, object, url, classloader

With the following code snippet, I am trying to load some class files into my project to create an object. Unfortunately, it seems that something is missing, because there are no classes loaded. What is it?

```
private static void myClassloader() throws Exception
{
    File file = new File(pathGeneratedClasses);
    try
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        URL url = file.toURL();
        URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
        ClassLoader sqlQuery = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        Class myClass = sqlQuery.loadClass("de.cimt.jaxb.JaxCodeGen");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: There is no error. The code just does not bring the class files into my existing project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sqlQuery.loadClass() will be returning the class you requested for, try assigning the returned value to something.
If no class is found then ClassNotFoundException will be thrown.

Comment: 3 WARNINGS: The value of the local variable myClass is not used +++ Resource leak: 'sqlQuery' is never closed +++ Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized JaxCodeGen.java

Comment: requested class should be loaded in myClass variable, try instantiating the loaded class.